# UIRoundedRectButton not responding to UIView category method

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a UIView category method to resize the frame of a UIView:

```
-(void)setFrameWidth:(NSInteger)aWidth andHeight:(NSInteger)aHeight
{
    CGRect labelFrame = self.frame;
    labelFrame.size = CGSizeMake(aWidth, aHeight);
    self.frame = labelFrame;
}
```

However, when I apply it to a UIRoundedRectButton:

```
//button for options
    optionsButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [optionsButton setTitle:@"Options" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [optionsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToOptions:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [optionsButton setFrameWidth:200 andHeight:50];
    optionsButton.center = CGPointMake(SCREEN_X_LENGTH_HALF, SCREEN_Y_LENGTH_TWO_THIRDS);
    [self.view addSubview:optionsButton];
```

it complains and says '-[UIRoundedRectButton setFrameWidth:andHeight:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x718a600'.

How do I get my category method to work on buttons?

Comment: the button even recognizes the method in the line I call it, but it still gives an error.

Comment: Uh, your method is called "setFrameWidth:andHeight", not "setButtonFrameWidth:andHeight:".

Comment: Sorry, I was testing a category method for UIButtons and forgot to change it. It should be setFrameWidth:andHeight. The problem is still there though. Original post edited.

Comment: Log the inheritance chain of the button.

Comment: Have you actually imported the category into the class that is making the call? I have copied and pasted your code exactly and have no issues...

Comment: And is the category .m being built into your app?

Comment: @Paul.s Yes, I imported it.

Comment: @Hot Licks, how do you log the inheritance chain and what do you mean by the .m being built into the app? It's definitely a file in the app. I renamed it at some point. Maybe that's what's wrong? It was working fine before and it randomly stopped working.

Comment: Can you confirm that the file being imported for the category is in fact the correct file. You can command+click on the `#import` statement to be taken to the file it references

Comment: Yup, the file is being imported.

Comment: Click on the .m file, and, in the "file info" or whatever display on the right, make sure the box is ticked to include it in your app.

Comment: You log the inheritance chain by studying the [Objective-C Runtime](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) reference.  First get the class from the instance, then repeatedly ask the class for it's superclass, logging each class name along the way.  (Remember that the names will be C strings, printed with `%s`, not `%@`.)

Comment: Thank you so very much! the .m file wasn't included (Target Membership) because of my renaming and bringing in the renamed files. Thank you once more!